# represent polynomials as linear combinations of a kind of radial basis functions

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials, approximation-theory, reverse-math, radial-basis-functions

Recently, I'm reading a paper [*Riesz representation theorem, Borel measures and subsystems of second-order arithmetic*](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271596/1-s2.0-S0168007200X01674/1-s2.0-0168007293902323/main.pdf). In page 2, the author said that polynomials are linear combinations of basic functions with rational coefficients, while the basic functions are defined as:
$p(x) = \begin{cases}
1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~,~ d(a,x)\leq s
\\
\frac{r-d(a,x)}{r-s}~,~ s < d(a,x) < r
\\
0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~,~ r \leq d(a,x)
\end{cases}
$

I think the graph of the basic function mentioned above is like a truncated cone, while some points of the basic function are not differentiable, so I'm confused that how a polynomial can be represented as a linear combination of basic functions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context around what the definitions actually say and mean. At face value, no function that is constant on an infinite set can be a polynomial. But that's most likely *not* what the author is actually claiming.